# "Can't open /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd6.leases for append." during start of ISC DHCP IPv6 Server

Tags: dhcpd

Trying to enable the ISC DHCP server for just IPv6 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I have downloaded and installed the DHCP server via the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

Then I have followed the instructions in the following resources, [Ubuntu Wiki DHCPv6](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DHCPv6), [SixXS - Configuring ISC DHCPv6 Server](http://www.sixxs.net/wiki/Configuring_ISC_DHCPv6_Server) and [Linux IPv6 HOWTO - Configuration of the ISC DHCP server for IPv6](http://mirrors.bieringer.de/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/hints-daemons-isc-dhcp.html) .

So from review all those resources it seems like I need to:

1. set a static IPv6 address for the Interface I want to run the DHCPv6 server from that is part of the IPv6 network subnet outside the DHCP range.
2. Edit the /etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf file to configure the DHCPv6 range etc.
3. Create the /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd6.leases
4. Manually start the DHCPv6 server.

**Setting the Static IP for eth0**

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 inet6 add 2001:db8:0:1::128/64
```

My dhcpd6.conf

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
log-facility local7;
subnet6 2001:db8:0:1::/64
{
   #Range for clients
   range6 2001:db8:0:1::129 2001:db8:0:1::254;
}
```

**Created the dhcpd6.leases file**

As indicated in the [dhcpd.leases man page](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpd.leases.5.html).

```
$ touch /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd6.leases  #Tried with sudo as well
```

**Manually starting the DHCPv6 server.**

Attempted to start the server using the following command:

```
$ sudo dhcp -6 -f -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf eth0
```

The problem, the DHCP will not start, with an append error for the dhcpd6.leases file as indicated below when running the manual start command noted above.

> Can't open /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd6.leases for append.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Still experiencing this problem? BTW, have you tried just `sudo start dhcpd`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like simple access rights for the file '/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd6.leases'. Check that it is owned by the same user that is running the dhcpd daemon and that that user has write rights to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and just used touch to create the file, after that it started as expected.

```
sudo touch /var/lib//dhcp/dhcpd6.leases
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran the same issue and solved it by:

```
chmod 0777 /var/lib//dhcp/dhcpd6.leases
```

Others did not work.